# Disable metacharacters in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, ansible

Perl has [\Q and \E operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Escape-sequences) in its regular expression toolkit:

```perl
"Foo (bar)" =~ /Foo \Q(bar)\E/; # Yup
"Foo (bar)" =~ /Fo. \Q(bar)\E/; # Yup
"Foo (bar)" =~ /Fo. \Q(ba.)\E/; # Nope
```

Does such a facility exist in Python? I am aware of the `in` operator to do literal string comparison, but my usecase is that I'm using the [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) Ansible module which relies on Python's regular expression library. I'd like something like this (if you can see the intent even though this doesn't work):

```yaml
- lineinfile:
    path: /somewhere/over/the/rainbow
    regexp: "^\Q{{ item }}\E$"
    line: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ some_list }}"
```

I am also aware of "[search_string](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-search_string)", but we are running Ansible 2.9 currently which does not support this facility.

Comment: You can use the `re.escape()` function.

Comment: `Ansible 2.8` <= [it's about time to upgrade](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#ansible-core-changelogs)

Comment: I've updated the original question to replace 2.8 to 2.9 which is actually what we use. We use Debian packaged versions of Ansible so eventually "use 2.11" will be a viable answer, but not for a little while.

Comment: I cannot see how I can work re.escape() into an Ansible play. I'll have a think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the filter [*regex_escape*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions), e.g.

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: test.txt
        regexp: "^{{ item|regex_escape }}$"
        line: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - '^f.*o(.*)$'
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat test.txt
^f.*o(.*)$
```

---

Below is the Ansible(Python) equivalent of the Perl example

```yaml
shell> cat test.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        path: test.txt
        regexp: "^{{ item.regexp }}$"
        line: "{{ item.line }}"
      loop:
        - {line: 'Foo (bar)', regexp: "{{ 'Foo ' ~ '(bar)'|regex_escape }}"}
        - {line: 'Foo (bar)', regexp: "{{ 'Fo. ' ~ '(bar)'|regex_escape }}"}
        - {line: 'Foo (bar)', regexp: "{{ 'Fo. ' ~ '(ba.)'|regex_escape }}"}
```

Running the playbook on an empty *test.txt* file in the check and diff mode gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook test.yml -CD

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************

TASK [lineinfile] **************************************************
--- before: test.txt (content)
+++ after: test.txt (content)
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Foo (bar)

changed: [localhost] => (item={'line': 'Foo (bar)', 'regexp': 'Foo \\(bar\\)'})
--- before: test.txt (content)
+++ after: test.txt (content)
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Foo (bar)

changed: [localhost] => (item={'line': 'Foo (bar)', 'regexp': 'Fo. \\(bar\\)'})
--- before: test.txt (content)
+++ after: test.txt (content)
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Foo (bar)

changed: [localhost] => (item={'line': 'Foo (bar)', 'regexp': 'Fo. \\(ba\\.\\)'})
```

The third item from the list is also reported *changed* despite the fact the *regexp* doesn't match. Quoting from module lineinfile parameter [regexp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-regexp): "*If the regular expression is not matched, the line will be added to the file ...*"

The task is idempotent. If the line is present in the file

```sh
shell> cat test.txt
Foo (bar)
```

there are no changes

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'line': 'Foo (bar)', 'regexp': 'Foo \\(bar\\)'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'line': 'Foo (bar)', 'regexp': 'Fo. \\(bar\\)'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'line': 'Foo (bar)', 'regexp': 'Fo. \\(ba\\.\\)'})
```